# How does the AsyncIO ControlCode work in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asyncsocket

In C# there is a low level [IOControl command for sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.iocontrol?view=netcore-3.1)
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.iocontrolcode?view=netcore-3.1), is a list of all the control codes that can be used with this command, I have noticed that one of them is called AsyncIO with the description 
`Enable notification for when data is waiting to be received. This value is equal to the Winsock 2 FIOASYNC constant.`
I've researched more and it seems that enabling AsyncIO would cause a SIGIO signal to be raised upon an IO event. [Source](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)
my question is, how do I use SIGIO in C# and how do I set the callback function using IOControl.

Comment: Why do that instead of using the xyzAsync methods? If you want to see how this works, check the source of the async methods, eg SendAsync and ReceiveAsync

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, maybe they work differently, maybe using AsyncIO will have certain benefits, I have no idea how AsyncIO works so maybe it's better, I don't know